# Is it ok to ask easily Google-able questions like "What is 'Feature Stapling'?" here?

Tags: discussion

Is it ok to ask easily Google-able questions like "What is 'Feature Stapling'?" here?

I assumed the answer was yes, but a comment on [one of my questions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33985/what-is-feature-stapling) made doubt this. I'm still in the early stages of trying to learn Sharepoint and I was thinking of asking more 'easily Google-able' questions like "What is a 'Property Bag'?", "What is a 'Delegate Control'?"

Why? Because the content doesn't exist on this QA site. Because even though I've looked some of these up on Google, they haven't quite 'clicked' yet, and I find asking it here would help my understand the concepts. Because asking here allows answers to be peer-reviewed, giving some measure of correctness.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer is **Yes**.

This site should be **the** SharePoint knowledge resource, with a definitive high-quality answer for every SharePoint question anyone may ever think of asking (within the boundaries of the [FAQ](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)).

Here are the related Meta.SO questions and answers:

[Embrace the non-Googlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5280/150991)

[How should we deal with Google questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8724/150991)

Comment: +1. Definitely allowed... However, keep in mind that answering takes time! Sometimes, people get frustrated when the asker has obviously not made any effort on their question. It helps if you indicate you've tried to do some research yourself or clarify what you are looking for. See also, [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: You might get down-voted, but it isn't against the rules.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that I get significantly better responses if I include links to what I HAVE looked at, and explained why I found them lacking. For isntance:

"I've been looking at http://blahblah.website.blah, and while it's got some great info, it's a little more technical than I understand at this point, and assumes prior knowledge of 2007. I was JUST assigned to head up the Sharepoint team, and really need to understand how permissions are assigned from AD before I can start the isntall and start exploring the product."

will get better answers than

"How do sharepoint permissions assign from AD?"

It's the same question, and hopefully a similar answer, but the context will help people answer appropriately to what you've already tried.